# How to handle errors in a select statement when attempting an insert or fail?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is there a good way to handle errors in a select statement when attempting an insert or fail?  Specifically, I want to insert elements into a table, but the select statement used to generate these elements is failing.  I would like to have all the elements where the select statement succeeded to be inserted, but for the overall statement to fail.  I thought that insert or fail would do this, but it does not.  More specifically, imagine if we defined a new SQLite function "log"

```c++
#include <string>
#include <sqlite3ext.h>
#include <cmath>
SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT1

extern "C" {
    int sqlite3_log_init(
        sqlite3 * db,
        char ** err,
        sqlite3_api_routines const * const api
    );
}

// Compute the log of the input
void mylog( 
    sqlite3_context *context,
    int argc,
    sqlite3_value **argv
){
    // Grab the number
    auto num = sqlite3_value_double(argv[0]);

    // If positive, take the log
    if(num > 0.) 
        sqlite3_result_double(context, log(num));

    // Otherwise, throw an error
    else {
        auto msg = std::string("Can't take the log of a nonpositive number");
        sqlite3_result_error(context,msg.c_str(),msg.size());
    }
}

// Initialize the functions
int sqlite3_log_init(
    sqlite3 *db,
    char **err,
    sqlite3_api_routines const * const api
){
    SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT2(api)

    // Register the log function
    if( int ret = sqlite3_create_function(
        db, "log", 1, SQLITE_ANY, 0, mylog, 0, 0)
    ) {
        *err=sqlite3_mprintf("Error registering log: %s",
            sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return ret;
    }

    // If we've made it this far, we should be ok
    return SQLITE_OK;
}
```

This can be compiled with

```
g++ -std=c++14 log.cpp -shared -o log.so -fPIC
```

Basically, the above function takes the log of its element.  For example,

```
sqlite> select log(1);
0.0
sqlite> select log(0);
Error: Can't take the log of a nonpositve number
```

Now, consider the following sequence of SQL operations

```
sqlite> .load "./log.so"
sqlite> create table foo (num real);
sqlite> insert into foo values (2.), (1.), (0.);
sqlite> create table bar (num real);
sqlite> insert or fail into bar select log(num) from foo;
Error: Can't take the log of a nonpositve number
sqlite> select * from bar;
sqlite>
```

Basically, the table bar is empty because the select statement failed on 0.  What I want to have happen is for the table bar to contain the elements log(2.) and log(1.), but the error to still be thrown.  Is there a way to have that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite's [ON CONFLICT clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) applies only to UNIQUE, NOT NULL, CHECK, and PRIMARY KEY constraints, so you would not be able to use INSERT OR IGNORE.

Once a user-defined function returns an error, it is not possible to suppress it.

You could say that the function's result is undefined, and let it return NULL (which you can then filter out).

Alternatively, get only those rows which have valid values:

```
INSERT INTO bar SELECT log(num) FROM foo WHERE num > 0;
```